# Hex To Dec To Custom RGB = Does not print the figure "0 (zero)"

Tags: php

As the title says, the output at the end won't show properly, if the hex value includes a "0X" or "00" value. Does anyone know a fix for it? (I am learning PHP, so please be more detailed, not brief explaining).

```
<div id="hex_rgb_calc">
        <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="Hex" value="#"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="CALCULATE">

    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['Hex']))
        {
            $hex = $_POST['Hex'];
            list($r, $g, $b) = sscanf($hex, "#%02x%02x%02x");
            $decRCALC = (dechex($r));
            $decGCALC = (dechex($g));
            $decBCALC = (dechex($b));
            $decRCALC = strtoupper($decRCALC);
            $decGCALC = strtoupper($decGCALC);
            $decBCALC = strtoupper($decBCALC);

    ?>
            <div id="separator">
            </div>
    <?php   
            echo "<br>1. Input: <br>$hex<br>";
            echo "<br>2. Output (Dec): <br>$r $g $b<br>";
            echo "<br>3. Custom (GB>R): <br>$decGCALC$decBCALC$decRCALC<br>";
        }
    ?>

</div>
```

To make an example:

Putting in the hex "020255" and converting it to my needed hex setup (in this case GBR, not RGB) should output it as the value "025502", but the actual output is "2552", the ZERO (0) values are missing, being cut.

Does anyone know how to fix that? I checked my HTML and CSS docs, I cannot find any kind of declaration which would obviously remove that value during the calculation.

Edit: Is there a way putting out the hex value in its corresponding color? :)

Comment: Can you give an example of what would output an `00` and `0X` value? When I try it, it writes zeros.

Comment: Try to convert "020255" and it should output 025502, but it is cutting off the zeros, so the final product will be "2552". Got what I mean?

Comment: With the "00" and "0X", I meant that, if a hex value contains those. X stays obviously for a random value of 0 to F.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`dechex`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php) function does not zero pad the hex string.  You'll have to do that yourself.

For example:

```
$decRCALC = str_pad(dechex($r), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Sadly, I cannot rep your post - "Vote Up requires 15 reputation".